# ChanSpy/Monitor multiple channels via one extension

Tags: asterisk, voip

This is my starting point:

```
extension x (radioDevice_1) <- is connected with -> meetme conference 123
extension y (radioDevice_2) <- is connected with -> meetme conference 456

ChanSpy a <- is monitoring -> extension x (radioDevice_1)
ChanSpy b <- is monitoring -> extension y (radioDevice_2)
```

But what I want to accomplish is:

```
extension z <- is monitoring both radio devices (over ChanSpys e.g.) -> extension x + y (concurrently - mixed audio signal)
```

I know in theorie that I can accomplish it by conferencing multiple **SIP** calls on client side.

But a much better way would be a server side solution in asterisk, I think.

Thank you very much for your sugestions and hints.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Use chanspy->meetme room_spy for both, after that use meetmeeroom_spy->monitoring extensions.

For connect chanspy/meetme use dedicated call/see call files

Comment: i really appreciate your reply and Thanks allot for helping,
Kindly refer me any helping link or a short prove of concept dialplan context etc

Comment: I am sorry, you request is not standart. You have do that yourself or hire person who can do that. I don't know why you need prove. Just create meetme room and join to it 3 channels.